# Opencart 3.0.2.0 Not Displaying Images

Tags: php, opencart

I have installed Opencart 3.0.2.0 in my Linux server. When I open my Store front page, it is not displaying Banner images, Product images, Manufacturer images.

I logged in to Admin panel and tried to upload images for product categories and products and those are successfully uploaded and stored in to  `/images/cache` folder. But in UI that images are not displaying.

[image]

Comment: Just ran into this same issue today and have not seen a solution. Will update you when i find one. You are not alone!

Answer (score 4):

It was a path issue to the **DIR_IMAGE** constant.

**How i got my server default root relative path.**

I created a file called path.php and added this code to it `echo getcwd();`.

I uploaded it to the root of my server online and this gave me my online relative path

accessing **http//{domain}/path.php** displays my relative path for me which I now used in my **config.php** file.

That was how I solve it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Open config.php in root folder and admin folder and search for **DIR_IMAGE**.

Update image path as below:

```
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/var/www/html/image/');
```

hope this helps